# In swift, while taking selfie, the image rotates(flips)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, camera

When i try to take selfie, the image rotates using swift

Sample images

Before:

[image: Before taking picture]

After:

[image: After taking picture]

I want the selfie camera as it shows, without rotate.

i am using UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

```
if(UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera))
    {
        picker!.delegate = self
        picker!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        self.picker!.showsCameraControls = true;
        self.present(picker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: you find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

How are you rendering your image?  The part that you are missing is that UIImage wraps a CGImage which may not actually be stored in the orientation you expect (ie its probably stored according to the camera sensor and not how you were holding the camera).  However, UIImage has an [imageOrientation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624141-imageorientation) enum that tells you how the image is supposed to be rendered.  UIImage is also smart enough to render itself in the correct orientation when you call one of the [draw](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624132-draw) methods.  If you are using CGImage you need to rotate the context yourself.  Start by inspecting the orientation and see if you need to perform a rotation to compensate.

Comment: Thank you for replying, i found the solution to keep the image without rotate after click the use photo, but i want a delegate function to call on click the capture button in camera,